# Сессия, как параметр функции по умолчанию

Tags: php

У меня есть функция getUser($id = ''), которая параметром принимает id пользователя, а возвращает информацию из БД для данного пользователя. В случае вызова без параметра функция должна брать информацию из БД для текущего пользователя (определяется по сессии).

```
 if (!empty($user)){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['auth']=true;
            $_SESSION['id'] = $user['id'];
            $_SESSION['login'] = $user['login'];
            $_SESSION['Name'] = $user['Name'];
            $_SESSION['Surname'] = $user['Surname'];
            $_SESSION['Email'] = $user['Email'];
            function getUser($user='id'){

                echo $user['login'].'<br>';
                echo $user['Name'].'<br>';
                echo $user['Surname'].'<br>';
                echo $user['Email'].'<br>';

            }
            getUser();
```

Comment: У меня задание заключается вот в чем: есть  функция getUser($id = ''), которая параметром принимает id пользователя, а возвращает информацию из БД для данного пользователя. В случае вызова без параметра функция должна брать информацию из БД для текущего пользователя (определяется по сессии).

Comment: ну вот так и опишите в первом посту _(его можно и нужно отредактировать, и вы имеете на это необходимые права)_

Comment: Хорошо, я переделаю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В описании функции установить параметром по умолчанию переменную строкой нулевой длины *(или false, если угодно)*, а в теле функции написать обычное условие с проверкой принимаемого значания, и в зависимости от него выполнять действия:

```
getUser();

function getUser($id = '')
{
    // Если вызов без параметра
    if (!$id) {
        // Работа с сессией
    } else {
        // Иначе передаём $id в sql-запрос
        // Работа с БД
    }
}
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое за помощь)